# Как в Java организована память на физическом уровне?

Tags: java, память, переменные, триггер, инициализация

Вопрос, который для некоторых может показаться глупым, но тем не менее, мне бы хотелось разобраться в этой теме, чтобы ещё на йоту поднять уровень личной программистской грамотности. Поскольку пишу программы на языке программирования  Java, то буду ссылаться на сущности из этого формального языка.

Насколько я понимаю, то вся ОЗУ представляет собой некоторый набор так называемых триггеров, простейших электронных устройств, которые могут находится в одном из устойчивых состояний в течение длительного периода времени. Я представляю это себе в качестве абстракции двоичного разряда. Это первый тезис, который хотелось бы уточнить.

Если я не совсем прав, то прошу опровергнуть мои слова. Затем, обладая некоторыми познаниями, рискну предположить, что некоторая совокупность триггеров образует единицу, которую принято называть «регистр». Опять-таки, лично в моём понимании это синоним машинному слову. А вот что такое машинное слово в контексте той же Java?

У нас есть 8 примитивных типов данных и каждый имеет свой фиксированный размер. Значит ли это, что для хранения значения определённого типа будет выбираться размер в зависимости от мощности самого типа данных? Допустим, если у нас есть тип `int`, то величина «машинного слова» будет составлять 4 байта для этого типа, а для типа `short`, к примеру, 2 байта? Для меня важно понять именно эти тонкости!

Также хотелось бы узнать, если предоставится такая возможность, как именно происходит запись значения в память. Тут уж снова без примера не обойтись. При создании экземпляра класса мы изначально инициализируем поля объекта при помощи инициализаторов и нестатических блоков инициализации в порядке их следования в исходном тексте программы, начиная с самого главного предка на вершине иерархии классов и спускаясь вниз. Что будет, если мы проинициализируем переменную уже в теле конструктора? Насколько я понимаю, то код, который прописан в теле конструктора, будет выполнен уже после  инициализаторов в теле класса.

То есть, если мы сначала объявляем переменную-член `int i;` и только потом проинициализируем её каким-нибудь значением в конструкторе, к примеру, напишем, что `i = 4;` значит ли это, что сначала, когда переменная только будет объявлена, в неё будет помещено значение по умолчанию `0`, а уже потом `4`? Или же сразу `4` будет помещено?

Объясните, пожалуйста, эту последовательность! Премного благодарю всех за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так оно и есть, если рассматривать классовую переменную примитивного типа, то пока вы не присвоите ей значение `i = 4;` то значение будет равно нулю. Это значение получается из того что при создании объекта ему выделяется участок памяти из кучи и размер памяти выделяемый для переменной типа `int` - фиксированный, то есть 4 байта. Хотя, описание класса и его переменных вместе со значениями находится в стэковой памяти и эти значения попадают в хип при создании объекта, то есть когда выполняется конструктор, то значения берутся уже из хипа.

[Вот](https://www.journaldev.com/4098/java-heap-space-vs-stack-memory) есть интересная статья на эту тему.

То что касается Java, то у вас нет доступа к физической памяти, и вы не можете получить адрес памяти по которому можно ссылаться на хранимое там значение. Все это доступно на языках низкого уровня, таких как C или C++, для которых есть JNI.

Comment: То есть, на этапе инициализации значения переменных сохраняются в стековой памяти, а уже потом, в момент вызова конструктора, перемещаются в кучу? Или в куче просто создаётся копия переменных, а стек затем очищается? Или как? Немного непонятен этот момент...

Comment: Да, имменно так.